# Laravel: How can I use where on a with statement?

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a url that looks like this: `site.com/athletes/1`
Each athlete can have many positions. From the url above, I am trying to get all athletes that belong to the position id of 1. My relationship is working great, but I am returning all athletes regardless of the url segment.

I have 3 tables: `athletes`, `positions` & `athlete_position`.

```
athletes
    id
    name

positions
    id
    name

athlete_position
    athlete_id
    position_id
```

**Athlete.php**

```
 public function positions()
 {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Position', 'athlete_position', 'athlete_id', 'position_id');
 }
```

**Position.php**

```
public function athletes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Athlete');
}
```

**AthleteController.php**

```
public function position(Position $position) {
    $athletes = Athlete::with('positions')->get();

    dd($athletes); // returns all athletes with the position relationship
}
```

It's like I need something like this:

```
$athletes = Athlete::with('positions')->where('position_id', '=', $position->id)->get();
```

But that's not using the relationship correctly. Is there a way to use a `where` clause in the model? That way when I visit the url `site.com/athletes/2` I am only getting back the athletes who belong to position id of 2?

Thank you for any suggestions!

**EDIT**

Everything is working great! Thank you so much @lagbox! Turns out once again I was over thinking everything.

Just a quick follow-up question. What is the best way to handle when an athlete belongs to position 1 *and* position 2?

When looping through the athletes in my view, should I just check the position id against the url segment to only show the specific position?

Something like:

```
@foreach($athletes as $athlete)
    @foreach($athlete->positions as $position)
        @if($position->id == {{ Request::segment(3) }}
          // Show the athlete
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Otherwise, since the athlete belongs to position id 1 and 2 that athlete will show up twice in the results. I only want the athlete to show up once - for the requested position.

For example:  `site.com/athletes/position/1`

This is what I am seeing now.

```
Athlete
    name: Foo
    position_id: 1

Athlete
    name: Foo
    position_id: 2

Athlete
    name: Bar
    position_id: 1

Athlete
    name: Bar
    position_id: 2
```

From the same url above, this is what I would like to get back:

```
Athlete
    name: Foo
    position_id: 1

Athlete
    name: Bar
    position_id: 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `whereHas` to check for existence of a relationship based upon conditions.

Though it seems like you should be able to just use the Position model instance you have for this as you have the inverse relationship setup already.

```
$athletes = $position->athletes;
// or to also have all those athletes positions
$athletes = $position->athletes()->with('positions')->get(); // egaer loading
// or if you have `athletes` loaded already
$athletes = $position->athletes->load('positions'); // with lazy eager laoding
```

I have a small Eloquent Relationships article that goes over some ways to query relationships [asklagbox - blog - Eloquent Relations](http://asklagbox.com/blog/eloquent-querying-relationships)

**Updated question:**
You probably don't need the athletes' positions at all since you know all the athletes you current have in that collection all have this particular one. If that is the case you can just return the `$position` to the view.

```
return view(..., ['position' => $position]);

Athletes for Position: {{ $position->name }}
<ul>
@foreach ($position->athletes as $athlete)
    <li>{{ $athlete->name }}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: This is absolutely fantastic. Thank you so much for your response. Your blog post is AWESOME! Everything is working great - I just have a follow-up question. I updated my question.

Comment: AAAHHH! I keep getting tunnel vision on the athlete and losing the fact I can leverage the inverse and use the position to get the athletes as well.  Thank you so much for your time!